# Angular acceleration in respect of speed, radius and rotations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I have a physics problem that I can't solve. The problem goes as follows:

> An objects spins around a point (radius $r$) $n-$times. After that the object is released at a given speed ($v$). The angular acceleration of the object is constant ($\alpha$) and it starts from angular rest ($v_0=0$). Find $\alpha$.

To me it doesen't seem logical that this can be done without knowing how long the object is actually spinning. Can anyone explane to me why the time is not needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information regarding either the torques or time or angular velocity is required to solve for angular acceleration.

Comment: You should have an equation that connects centripetal acceleration, velocity, and radius.

Comment: Could it be that there is a dot over alpha, so the question is about angular velocity?

Comment: Probably unstated assumption: the object started from angular rest. Sometimes it helps to re-state in linear terms. A object starts from rest, and experiences constant accelration $a$ until reaching displacement $s$ at which time it has velocity $v$. Find $a$ in terms of $s$ and $v$. This version has slight frills in the form of using $v$ rather $\omega$ and $n$ turns rather thant $\theta$ radians, but it is the same problem.

Comment: @dmckee's hint should help a lot. Something else that might help is to calulate the number of cycles $n$ and the final velocity $v$ for the case that $\alpha$ and the total time $t$ would be given. The resulting set of equations will allow you to express $t$, as a function of $v$ and $n$, which both are given in this problem.

Comment: There is a kinematic equation that relates the distance traveled under constant acceleration to speed. Find the angular equivalent of this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the acceleration is due to a force $F$ applied to the object of mass $m$. The total work done is

$$ W = F d = F (2 \pi r) n \tag{1} $$

The work is transformed to kinetic energy, such that $$ W = K $$ $$F (2\pi r) n = \frac{1}{2} m v^2  \tag{2}$$

The force required to accelerate the object with $\alpha$ is $$F = m (\alpha r) \tag{3}$$

Can you use the above (2) and (3) to solve for $\alpha$?